# How can we make our Userdefined Exception part of Compile Time

Tags: java, exception

```
public class NoSufficientFundException extends Exception
{
    String strValue;

    public PositionException(String value) {
        this.strValue = value;
    }
}
```

For example if i do the above way, the exception `NoSufficientFundException` also includes `RuntimeException`.

Basically how to make Userdefined Exception as part of Compile Time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between *checked* and *unchecked* exceptions. When an exception is checked then you need to wrap it around try-catch.

```
try{
// open File
new FileReader(...)
}catch(IOException e){
// handle a CHECKED exception
}
```

I think what you are asking is how to not have to check for this catch. These are called uncheced exceptions. You can do this by extending `RuntimeException`. You no longer to catch these exceptions, and instead the JVM will catch them and print the log.

Answer (score 0):

It is "a part of compile time" now. You have to extend `RuntimeException` to get unckeched exceptions - not checked at compile time.